# removeObjectsAtIndexes causing a crash

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsindexset

Can't figure out whats causing the crash here. Im enumerating over a `NSMutableArray` and placing the indexes of certain objects into a mutable index set, then attempting to remove the corresponding objects from the array. here is my code

```
  NSMutableIndexSet *itemsToRemove;

UIBarButtonItem *item;
NSUInteger index;

for (item in self.rightView.toolbarItems)
{
    if (item.tag == MLPAD_RIGHT_VC_BACK_TO_CENTRAL_ITEM_TAG){
        [itemsToRemove addIndex:index];
        index ++;
    }
}

[self.rightView.toolbarItems removeObjectsAtIndexes:itemsToRemove];
```

the last line is crashing and giving me an `EX_BAD_ACCESS`.

any ideas why?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not allocating/initializing `itemsToRemove` - if you're using ARC, it's initialized to  `nil`, if not, it potentially contains garbage - neither one is acceptable if you want it to be passed as an argument later...

Neither do you initialize `index` to zero...

(Why am I suspecting that you're coming from a managed language?...)

Unrelated to the crash, but it's still a semantic error: you have to increment `index` even if the conition is not met:

```
for (item in self.rightView.toolbarItems)
{
    if (item.tag == MLPAD_RIGHT_VC_BACK_TO_CENTRAL_ITEM_TAG) {
        [itemsToRemove addIndex:index];
    }
    index ++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your primary problem is that `itemsToRemove` never gets initialized. You can't add an object to an NSMutableIndexSet that isn't really an NSMutableIndexSet - try setting `itemsToRemove = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init]` or similar.

I also think where you have the statement `index++` might be throwing some things off - if you only increment the index when you find an item you want to remove, you're effectively removing the first `itemsToRemove.count` items, instead of the actual items you want to get rid of. Think about incrementing the index unconditionally instead.

Comment: Good catch about the conditional increment. +1.

Comment: Thanks! I've actually always wondered about this - in your opinion, is it better to do it his proposed way (with the increment correction, obviously), or to iterate over `self.rightView.toolbarItems.copy` and just remove the objects from `self.rightView.toolbarItems` when the condition matches?

Comment: ***DO NOT FOR THE LOVE OF GOD EVER DO THAT!*** Mutating a mutable collection while enumerating is a serious semantical error. It even invokes an NSException as it makes no sense (just try to imagine it using a small array...)

Comment: @H2CO3 I believe Tim is talking about creating an immutable copy of the collection, then iterating over the copy and removing items from the mutable collection.

Comment: @JodyHagins that's not good either - if it's an array, the copy will continue to have as many items as oroginally, but the original shrinks, so the indices will be erroneously shifted.

Comment: @H2CO3: I'm both making a copy as JodyHagins suggests, and not using indices to remove the objects; I'm talking about a simple `for (id item in mutableArray.copy) { [mutableArray removeObject:item]; }` (usually with a condition, omitted here for clarity). No index offset problems, no mutation during enumeration. Objections?

Comment: @Tim that should be good this way at first glance. (However I'm still not convinced. I'm afraid a bit.)

Comment: @Tim Yeah, that's how I read your original comment.  Obviously, you have to pay to make a copy of the original, but you are inserting into a mutable set for the ones you are removing.  If you are consistently removing a small number of items, the original method is probably better, but if you are going to remove more than some number just under half the collection size, then the copy method will probably be better.  I think under purely random behavior, the copy will win, but program characteristics are seldom random.  I'd just pick one and let analysis guide me if there was an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues.  Not allocating `itemsToRemove`, not initilializing `index` (builtin stack variables are not auto-initialized) and not incrementing `index` on every loop iteration.

```
NSMutableIndexSet *itemsToRemove = [NSMutableIndexSet new];
NSUInteger index = 0;

for (UIBarButtonItem *item in self.rightView.toolbarItems)
{
    if (item.tag == MLPAD_RIGHT_VC_BACK_TO_CENTRAL_ITEM_TAG){
       [itemsToRemove addIndex:index];
    }
    ++index;
}

[self.rightView.toolbarItems removeObjectsAtIndexes:itemsToRemove];
```

The `index` type of error can be minimized by using the block enumeration method, which passes in the current index.